# Storing words into a hashtable

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, hashtable, valgrind

I have a file that contains English words in a txt file, each word in a new line.
I'm a beginner in C. I'm using a `load` and `unload` functions to store all the words into a hashtable (separate chaining) and unload them from memory, but has ran into some problems.

The functions (the code in main.c is correct):

> load:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

#define SIZE 26

typedef  struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH+1];
    struct node *next;
}node;

unsigned int hash_num = 0;
node *hashtable[SIZE];  //26 letters in alphabet

node *head = NULL;

// hashfunction
unsigned int hash(char const *key)  
{
    unsigned int hash= tolower(key[0]) - 'a';
    return hash % SIZE;
}

/**
 * Loads dictionary into memory.  Returns true if successful else false.
 */
bool load(const char* dictionary)
{

    unsigned int hash_index=0;

    FILE *fp = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open %s",dictionary);
        return false;
    }

    //dictionary 


    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        node *temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (temp == NULL)
        {
            unload();
            fclose(fp);
            return false;
        }


        if(fscanf(fp , "%s", temp->word) == 1)   //storing word of dictionary in my new_node -> word
        {
            hash_index = hash(temp->word); 
            head= hashtable[hash_index];    //head always points to first element of linked list (containting word of dictionary)


            temp->next = head;  
            head = temp;        


            hash_num++;
        }
        else    //if fscanf couldn't store the word (return 0)
        {
            free(temp);    //free last temp
            break;
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return true;

}
```

> unload:

```
bool unload(void)
{

    for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        if(hashtable[i] != NULL)      //if hashtable isn't NULL (has nodes)
        {
            node *cursor = hashtable[i];        //cursor points at head of individual linked list
            while(cursor != NULL)       //free them
            {
                node *temp = cursor;
                cursor = cursor->next;
                free(temp);
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Can anyone tell me if the logic is correct? Whenever I run valgrind it tells me that all my nodes were allocated but just 3 free'd.

```
total heap usage: 143,094 allocs, 3 frees, 8,014,288 bytes allocated
LEAK SUMMARY:
==15903==    definitely lost: 8,013,040 bytes in 143,090 blocks
==15903==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15903==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When checking the provided source code (missing "dictionary.h"), the main problem is locating in the `load()` function.

**Problem 1 (Main)** - the `hashtable[]` is never updated when adding a new word/node (after computing `hash_index = hash(temp->word);`).

> To store the updated linked-list (managed as reversed), it is
>   necessary to update the `hashtable[hash_index]` with the new node
>   pointer (the allocated `temp` node).

```
temp->next = head;
head = temp;

hashtable[hash_index] = head; // update the hashtable[] pointer

hash_num++;
```

> Alternate solution without global variable `head`.

```
temp->next = hashtable[hash_index]; //head always points to first element...
hashtable[hash_index] = temp; // update the hashtable[] pointer

hash_num++;
```

Instead of

```
temp->next = head;
head = temp;

hash_num++;
```

**Problem 2 (Small)** - the `hashtable[SIZE]` is never initialized.

> In the `unload()` function, in the for-loop, the if-condition
>   `if(hashtable[i] != NULL)` assumes that each item of the array is
>   initialized to NULL.

Add at the beginning the `load()` function or before calling it, a for-loop to initialize each pointer.

```
for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
{
    hashtable[i] = NULL;
}
```

**Problem 3 (Potential Bug Source)** - as suggest by reviewer, the use of `head`, declared as a global variable `node *head = NULL;` could be a potential source of bug.

> In the `load()` function, the variable `head` is used as a temporary
>   storage but could store value during software run. If a read operation
>   is performed without a well-known write operation before, the result
>   could be an unexpected error even if the compilation doesn't detect
>   error or warning.
>
> The best way is to reduce the number of global variable as much as
>   possible.

**Enhancement (Reverse the linked-list)** - because the managed linked-list is adding new items in the front, here is a solution to add new items in the end.

```
node *first = hashtable[hash_index];
if (first == NULL) {
    hashtable[hash_index] = temp;
}
else {
    temp->next = NULL; // ending the list
    while (first->next!=NULL) {
        first = first->next;  // loop until last node
    }
    first->next = temp; // linking to the last node
}

hash_num++;
```

Instead of

```
head= hashtable[hash_index];    //head always points to first element ...

temp->next = head;  
head = temp;        

hash_num++;
```

Comment: A million thanks for the detailed explanation. For the problem 2, someone else told me in another forum that whenever I initialize a global variable, it's initialized to NULL by default that's why I didn't initialized it explicitly..